# Eclipse opening and then closing immediately

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse keeps showing the splash screen and then closing immediately after...I just downloaded it so I haven't had the opportunity to make a work space. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, the file has already been unzipped at this point I have no idea as to what I should do about this.

Comment: What is your OS and Eclipse version? Is Java runtime installed?

Comment: windows and mars.1 32-bit and yes

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have installed Java JDK properly

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it (Eclipse) encounters a problem that does not warrant launching a dialog, Eclipse saves a report in the workspace log file. The log file can be looked at in four alternative ways.

1. Locate the file yourself, see    workspace/.metadata/.log.
2. Start Eclipse using -consoleLog. This will print the messages
   that normally go to the .log file in the enclosing shell/command window. When the Java VM suffers a hard crash, it produces a    separate logging file named something like hs_err_pidXXXXX.log.    These files are also helpful for diagnosing 
   problems.

(Other two might not be useful in your case)

3. Window > Show View > PDE Runtime > Error Log. This gives you a view 
       with the contents of the .log file.
4. Help > About Eclipse Platform >    Configuration Details. This
   prints    out a great number of details    about the environment and
   also    concatenates the .log file. Great for    including in a bug
   report.

[Source](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that Java installed properly..

Uninstall Java and install again, this worked for me